# PDFTeXify failed to create a PDF file for a very minimal document

Tags: pdftex

[image]

How can I solve this PDF building problem in WinEdt?

Comment: Have to tried adding some "real" content between the `\begin{document}` and the `\end{document}` tags like a simple piece of text?

Comment: Which engine are you using? Because you should be using "pdflatex" I think.

Answer (score 4):

`\title{<title>}` is only meant to *store* the content for a title, which will eventually be set by `\maketitle`. So, add an `\author{<author>}` (it functions similar to `\title`, but not necessary for the title to be printed though) and then execute `\maketitle` and peace will be restored.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\title{A title}
\author{An author}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

The reason for the error is because your document is completely empty (since `\title` doesn't set anything). As such, TeX doesn't create any output (PDF) and that's why WinEdt complains.